# how to convert this SQL statement for FluentPDO code

Tags: php, mysql

I made this SQL statement to use in a project i'm working on and i have used FluentPDO before but it has been a while and i have never used a subquery in it before, so was wondering if anyone out there knows a good way to do this, i know you can do a JOIN but i am not really familiar with that method and never seen it used before so i don't know enough to make it work, i'm trying to brush up on it so i can do this myself.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users 
WHERE  username = 'admin' 
       AND password = 'testing' 
       AND company_id IN (SELECT company_id 
                          FROM   company
                          WHERE  subdomain = 'testing');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $db->from('users')
        ->innerJoin('company ON users.company_id = company.company_id')
        ->where('username', 'admin')
        ->where('password', 'testing')
        ->where('subdomain', 'localhost')
    ->fetch();
```

I figured out the answer, and wanted to post it for anyone that was wondering the same way i was.